# Probability for two events - Cans in bags

Tags: probability

I believe I have this correct but here is my question:

A bag containing 4 cans and 3 bottles. A second bag contains 2 cans and 4 bottles. One bag is chosen at random and from the selected bag, one object is drawn.

### What is the probability that a can is drawn?

The firstbag should be (1/2)(4/7) = 2/7
The second bag should be (1/2)(1/3) = 1/6

2/7 + 1/6 = 19/42 ~ 45.2%

Comment: Yes, it's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is absolutely correct. The following tree diagram illustrates it

[image]

Just multiply the probabilities at the branches and add the favourable ones to get your answer